# How can I add values for each propery in a sass mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I am newbie with Sass and I am creating a nested run with the next values

```
.heightAndWidth {
    height: 21px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

But I would like extend this rule and add 10 px in a specificclass, instead of 21, 31 but reusing the nested rule is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "nested run"?

Comment: @inane Why did you post that as a possible duplicate? It's not a duplicate in any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry this is scss

```
@mixin heightAndWidth($px) {
  width : $px; 
  height : $px; 
}

.box { @include heightAndWidth(10px); }
```

here is sass

```
=widthAndHeight($px)
  width:    $px
  hight:    $px

.box
  +widthAndHeight(10px)
```

http://www.sass-lang.com/guide

you can find to documentation here.

```
$a = 100px; 
div {
    background: black;
    height:100px;
}
.one {
    width: $a;
    $a = $a+100;
}
.two {
   width: $a;
   $a = $a+100;
}
.three {
   width: $a;
   $a = $a+100; 
}
```

Comment: ok I understand your example but is it possible dinamically to and 10 px to 21, for example? Thanks for your explanation

Comment: as far as i know, you can't do that, the only way I will put it up shortly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3zbcu1a4/

Comment: Thank you @wlin your perspective it was cool for my implementation but I have the next doubt if the parameter in the function is "%" instead of px or em, gives me an error, what could it be the approach in this instance?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3zbcu1a4/1/ this for %

Comment: thank you @wlin for your explanation but I would like to do it with your first piece of code in the inside of mixin, for example @mixin `heightAndWidth($%)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72937/discussion-between-inane-and-wlin).